# issue with querying of multiple tabs inside same sheet

Tags: google-sheets, tabs, spreadsheet

i am trying to query number of response, country name and month from one tab but i also need it to display the name of country corresponding to country number which is in a different tab
this is my statement
=QUERY({CSAT!$A$2:$F$34;Countries!$A$2:$B$11},"SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col5 WHERE Col1 = 'Jun-21' ON Col2 = Col3 ")

i keep getting an error saying that there are missing values on lateral array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number of columns from both sheets must be the same if you want to append them in the query. Using the query with different number of columns (6 vs 2) will result into:

[image: result]

If we get 2 columns from both sheets:

```
=QUERY({CSAT!$A$2:$B$34;Countries!$A$2:$B$11})
```

Error is not shown:
[image: result]